# Kill process by process id only if it is a node process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am killing a process by process id, which works, however, if the process id gets killed somehow and a new process starts taking that process id it will be killed.

So, my thought is to only kill a process if it is a node process which sounds less destructive than just killing any process by process id.

The problem is, node doesn't seem to have a way to get process information by process id. So, is there a way I can get this process information so when I do a kill I only kill node processes?

```
let settings = require('./settings.json')
let pid = settings.pid
os.platform() == 'win32' ? process.kill(pid) : process.kill(-pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the ps command from nodejs and check that the command column is "node":

```
ps -p <PID>
```

you will need to parse the result of that and check what the CMD column is if it's "node" then that should mean that it's a nodejs process.

Comment: This would only work if you are running on linux, but there may be a windows equivalent command.